# Sort contact list by name using Java stream.sort()

Tags: java

In my code I want to sort the contacts by their firstname, so I wrote the below method which is not working for me. Actually this code instead of giving me a sorted contact list it is giving me a normal unordered contactlist

```
public Set<Contact> sortContacts() {
    Set<Contact> sortedContacts = contactList.stream().sorted((c1, c2) -> c1.firstName.compareTo(c2.firstName)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    return sortedContacts;
}
```

Comment: The set created from `Collectors.toSet()` is unsorted. I suggest you use a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each data structure has its own unique feature. A `Set` is an unordered list with no duplicate elements in it.

You need to use an `Array` or a `List` in order to keep the positions of your elements intact, such as in the case of sorting.

You can go through this [blog](https://beginnersbook.com/2014/07/difference-between-list-and-set-in-java/#:%7E:text=Set%20is%20an%20unordered%20collection,doesn%27t%20allow%20duplicate%20elements.) to understand the difference between a `Set` and a `List`.

You can also modify the last chained method `.collect(Collectors.toSet())` to `.collect(Collectors.toList())`, to acheive your desired result.

Comment: thank u guys my first question had get answered this fast. unexpected guys

Comment: Note that using a list is different insofar as it will not remove duplicate entries. If you want to remove duplicate entries, you need either to use `.distinct()` before collecting, or collect to an insertion-order-preserving set like `LinkedHashSet`.